# PHP timestamp conversion

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a page that allows users to create and submit posts. 
In order to determine the time of their post, I used `timestamp` in mysql.

Here's a sample of one of the timestamps in my data:
`2017-05-07 16:12:44.415472`

Using php (or javascript if there's actually no other way), how can I make it display something like this:
`Sunday, May 07, 2017 4:00PM`

I also want to display the post's age like `posted 2 hours ago`.
I figured if you put a timestamp every time the page reloads, and then compare/subtract it to the post's original timestamp, it would create a result similar to what I described. Is this however possible? If so, how can I do this?

Comment: Do please first search google for PHP format timestamp and JavaScript convert date to days ago. Your questions are VERY FAQs. Also please ask one question at a time (but search first)

Comment: Okay sir my bad...I admit the question was pretty vague too. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In php you can format the variable coming from mysql.

```
$date = new DateTime("2017-05-07 16:12:44.415472");
$formatted = $date->format("N, F d, Y H:i");
```